# How to format value in Dial Gauge to display only millions in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I want to implement Dial Gauge in my report to display current value versus goal value.

But cant understand how to format number? Instead of 18,136,616M I simply want to see 18M

[image]

[image]

Other visuals has Display Units, so you can easy choose how to display it.

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this visual just doesn't have the necessary controls to adjust the number format.

You may have better luck with the [tachometer visual](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380937), otherwise, you'll probably need to get in contact with [Cloudfront](http://www.cloudfronts.com/contact-us/) if you need their Dial Gauge visual specifically.

Comment: Thanks. As always best help.